# Upload Excel to OneDrive without Closing

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, onedrive

I have a project plan in an Excel workbook on OneDrive that I share to my team via a read-only Url.

I have the plan open all day in Excel 2013 making changes as the day evolves; these I save as I go.

In Windows explorer I see the file date/time has updated and the file has a green tick, but in OneDrive the file doesn't update.  The update online only happens if I close the file on my PC.

Is there a way I can force the file to upload without closing it - or a Macro I can write to force this action.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like no solution to the actual issue - I've constructed a macro from snippets around the web - posted here in case it's useful:

```
Sub SaveCloseReopen()

    Dim strCMD As String

    strCMD = "CMD /C PING 10.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 10000 >NUL & Excel.exe " & Chr(34) & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & Chr(34)

    Shell strCMD, vbHide
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Waits 10 seconds which seems like enough time for the file to update - although this is a week point in the code!